# App leave blank space in bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-webview

Guys My apps are leaving a blank space for navigation buttons on the bottom of screen.

Please help me rectify that

[image]

as we can a blank space is left on the bottom whereas other apps are normal.

Here is my style.xml code:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>
```

Here is the activity code in Manifest file :

```
<activity
     android:name="unknown"            
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:launchMode="singleInstance"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
```

**EDIT : I did everything but nothing worked but the problems seems with the editors. I created an app with android studio with all the same code and themes It shows it fine but When I use eclipse, it show the blank space in the bottom.
This is so annoying.**

Comment: can you post your xml file please ?

Comment: Could you post your styles.xml file please?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with xml because the whole app is displayed like this. I will update this question with xml though

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Add your `styles.xml` and `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: Eclipse is not supported anymore for a long time, maybe it has broken toolchain, use Android Studio for development.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
< activity
        android:name="unknown"            
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
```

Comment: so what is your application theme?

Answer (score 0):

To solve it you should add `android:xlargeScreens=true` to `supports-screens` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the theme

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

OR you can try below theme

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

instead of

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create following style in styles.xml

```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarTransparentstatusBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

To Your activity in Manifest.xml, add following

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarTransparentstatusBar"
```

To your activity layout xml file add

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Add following to activity onCreate method.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a browser based app there is a known issue in Chrome being tracked by the development team where a white bar is appearing after new theme installs. It may be related. I have an html intro screen with the same issue. Displays perfect in Firefox and IE, in Chrome I get a white space at the bottom and nothing helps; padding, margins, themes in AS etc.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your min sdk level like below in build.gradle.

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.test.com"
minSdk 26                // change min sdk level to 26 or above
versionCode 4
versionName "24"
multiDexEnabled true
dataBinding {
enabled = true
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).