# Blank space on bottom of all layout activities

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have a mobile app that works perfectly on larger devices (tablets) but in cellphones, it keeps showing a blank space **on the bottom of all layouts** across the app.

In this example I'll show the login layout (no action bar).

I'm testing in two physical mobile devices (both with the problem): **Motorola E13** and **Samsung A71**.

This is the result in the mobile devices (printscreen from physical device):

[image]

This is my `login_layout.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_rdscan_black"
            android:layout_width="300dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlined">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtLogin"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:hint="CPF"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/smaller_font_size" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlined"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Senha"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/smaller_font_size" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:text="Entrar"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/smaller_font_size"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_button_dark_rounded"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:progressTint="@color/primary_active"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLoginVersionSNHash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/app_version"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/accent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSettingsWifi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_wifi"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="#272B35"
        app:rippleColor="@color/accent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the `styles` I'm using:

```
<style name="AppThemeLogin" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">0dp</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_active</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Already tried this topics with no success:

- [App leave blank space in bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078344/app-leave-blank-space-in-bottom)
- [Action bar removal leaves blank space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095395/action-bar-removal-leaves-blank-space)

This is driving me nuts. Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you test on the emulator? I test your layout (removing the source you don't provided) on the android 13 emulator and didn't see the blank space.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT no, just on physical devices. Is it possible that other layouts on the app are causing this behavior? What is crazy is that on tablets as I said before, everything looks normal.

Comment: The tablets' aspect ratio are smaller than the mobile phone. According to your image, it looks like the CoordinatorLayout didn't fill the windows for the height. You can test it on the emulator to check if the problem only appears on the special physical devices or not.

Comment: Will it fill if you are using a LinearLayout instead of CoordinatorLayout ?

Comment: @SunilSunny just tried and the blank space continues. Completely removed coordinator layout. I'm starting to think that is a problem with the design library I'm using. Since we need to support old devices, I'm afraid to update it and then this old devices start to crash or something like that.

Comment: @SunilSunny Updated design library packages. The problem still persists.

Comment: I can't find any issue with the code you posted, maybe try commenting out everything inside the CoordinatorLayout and give it a green or red background and see if none of the contents are causing any issues.

Comment: Nowdays we use androidx for all libraries, for reference  `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and while creating new project I don't see any option to create project without `android.* artifacts` and I have test this XML with latest library and it shows perfect in devices.

Comment: @Harshali yes, this project in from early days of Xamarin. This further reinforces the idea that there is a problem with the old libraries.

Comment: @gregoryp, Did you able to solve UI issue after upgrading old libraries?

Comment: @Harshali I updated the old libraries to the maximum allowed by the support library I'm using and with no success, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Design different for Tablet and Mobile Device. I think, problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for a coordinatorlayout. Why not just use a modern ConstraintLayout.  androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout. The other obvious problem is you are still using the old support controls. You should be using all androidx controls. I doubt even if you fixed the problem Google Play Console would accept your app on Google Play. I think the lowest allowable Api an app can be built with is now Android 13.

Comment: I'm using old libraries to support devices that I have on customers running Android < 13.   The app is not on Google Play, so I'm not worried about that. We have our own update feature inside the app. So, as you told that nowadays the lowest allowable Api is Android 13, do you have any other ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: All the androidx libs will run on older devices.

Comment: I'll try and let you know the results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can see plenty of examples on my GitHub, There is a mixture of Xamarin.Android, Android.Net7 and Android.Net8 projects. Just about every layout in every project is using an androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout. You'll find that screens designed with ConstraintLayout look just the same on phones or tablets. Since the Android designer is pretty much useless in Visual Studio 2022, you should install Android Studio and create a project with the same name as your existing project. Create all your layouts in Android Studio and when finished copy/paste the XML of the layout to an empty XML layout file of the same name in your VS project. Long term wise you may want to get a copy of Beyond Compare or something like it for maintenance purposes. Always modify the layout in Android Studio, and then open both files with Beyond Compare and push your changes back to the VS XML file. The AS designer is a great designer, so it is well worth learning how to use it. https://github.com/gmck